# How to Send data or my option of dialog option to editText in android

Tags: android

How I can do dialog option like (Select you option) and when user select any option that option data will be send to editText in android?

Anyone have any idea؟

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun createDialog() {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.item, null)
    AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setView(view)
        .setNeutralButton("Cool") { _: DialogInterface, i: Int ->
            val checkedId = view.radioButtonGroup.checkedRadioButtonId
            val selectedRadioGroupText = view.findViewById<RadioButton>(checkedId)?.text
            selectedRadioGroupText?.let {
                coolEditText.setText(it)
            }
        }.show().create()
}
```

so create your dialog like that inflate your RadioGroup and add it into your alert dialog. when your neutral button is clicked get your checked radio button id. note that it can be null. check if its not null and set it as your TextViews text.